# Correlation ID not found error on iOS build on AppCenter

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, visual-studio-app-center

I get the following error when I try to deploy a react-native iOS app on AppCenter

```
##[error]"{\"message\":\"Not found. Correlation ID: ec546922-3dbd-488e-80fb-15dcc8a51a84\",\"statusCode\":404,\"code\":\"Not Found\"}"
```

It started happening last week, but I haven't changed any native dependency, so I'm not sure what is this. Also, the android deployment works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, ios was working fine but not Android. Also, an other Android release pipeline was working fine. The issue was company name missing in the app slug. E.g Company name is Tesla and the build you'd like to deploy is battery then app slug should be Tesla\battery. Initially, app slug was battery only. After I added Tesla\ in front of battery, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Should the app slug be "Tesla/battery" instead of "Tesla\battery" (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute?view=azure-devops and https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/issues/869#issuecomment-629019982)?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue, but it resolved on its own without us doing any change. It might not be the case for you, but maybe try to rebuild the app a few times if it was working in the history and you haven't done any change.

Answer (score 0):

For people having still the problem, adding the email from our Jenkins (jenkins-appcenter@...) as a collaborator worked.